# FtpWebRequest doesn't delete file through FTP - But can find file

Tags: .net-core, ftpwebrequest

**Hello there.**

I've found an issue in a current script i am working on.

When i attempt to use FTPWebRequest to Delete a file from FTP URI - I stumple into an error where it actually does find the file (checking existence), however - it just doesn't delete it for some reason.

I can find the file, and edit it through my script - no issues; it just doesn't trigger the delete if asked.. Let me give you an example of the ActionResult that starts it all.

```
    if (server.Protocol.Equals("FTP"))
    {

        Uri serverUri = null;
        serverUri = new Uri($"{server.Server}/TheIsle/Saved/Databases/Survival/Players/{dino.SteamId}.json", UriKind.Absolute);
        if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
        var isDeleted = DinosaurWorker.DeleteTextFromFtpURI(config, _context, serverUri, dino);
        if (isDeleted)
            return Ok();
        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

As you see here, DeleteTextFromFtpURI is being called (isDeleted)

This is the DeleteTextFromFTPURI - where it supposidly does include:

> WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

```
 internal static bool DeleteTextFromFtpURI(NetworkConnection config, ApplicationDbContext context, Uri serverURI, Dinos dino, string user = "")
        {
            WebClient request = new WebClient();

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(config.Username, config.Password);

            try
            {
                byte[] newFileData = request.DownloadData(serverURI);
                string fileString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
                var player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(fileString);
                var dinosaurDbName = dino.Dinosaur.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name;
                if (player.CharacterClass == dinosaurDbName && player.Growth == "1.0")
                {
                    SavePlayer(context, dino, player);
                    var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(player);
                    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x);
                    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverURI);

                    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
                    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(config.Username, config.Password);
                    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                    response.Close();
                }

                LogAction(context, dino.SteamId, $"Dinosaur: {player.CharacterClass} should have been deleted", user);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The LogAction completes, i can see it in the websites logs that the file should be deleted, however - i am still able to see the file.

Let me just rephrase that the FTP Connection does work, and it does check if the file exist - It does find the file through ftp, but the delete doesn't happen.

I've checked user folder perms, and my site can edit the file just fine.. It just simply doesn't delete.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed an error in my own code, regarding the WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
There was not put in a return false; in (in case it didn't meet the criteria).

Solution found.